# SSH connection for different user names in Amazon EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, remote-connection

I am trying to connect two EC2 instances using SSH.

SSH connection for the same user name on the two instances gets connected without any issue. While trying to connect with differentuser name I get a “PERMISSION DENIED” error. Following is the debug information for the SSH Command:

```
ssh -v -i /home/A/.ssh/Master_KeyPair.pem B@xx.xx.xxx.xxx

OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xxx.xxx [xx.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/xx.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/xx-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/nXg_HDP_RHEL65_Master_KeyPair.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 1):

If login to xx.xx with user A succeeded, that means that ssh configuration of A, which should be in XX.XX:/home/A/.ssh/ , is there and matches your Master_KeyPair.pem

Since the same does not work for user B, then the file is not available at xx.xx:/home/B/.ssh/

So you should login to xx.xx with user A, 'su' into user B and copy the key there.